# Как передать динамический массив в другую функцию?

Tags: c++

Объясните, пожалуйста, каким образом я могу передать динамический масив в функцию DisplayCountries?

```
const int n_Country = 2;

struct Country
{
char name[100];
char capital[100];
int population;
double area;
};

int main() {

Country* List;
List = new Country[n_Country];


for (int i = 0; i < n_Country; i++)
{
    cout << "Name = ";
    cin >> List[i].name;
    cout << "Capital " << endl;
    cin >> List[i].capital;
    cout << "Population " << endl;
    cin >> List[i].population;
    cout << "Area " << endl;
    cin >> List[i].area;
  }

}

void DisplayCountries() {
cout << "--------- Result ---------------";
for (int i = 0; i < n_Country; i++)
{
    cout << List[i].name << ", " << List[i].capital << ", " << List[i].population << ", " << List[i].area << endl;
}
```

}

Comment: Прямо вместе с размером и передавайте. Например -- `...DisplayCountries(list, n_Country);... void DisplayCountries (Counry *lst, size_t n) { ... }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто немного отредактировал Ваш код:

```
const int n_Country = 2; //глобальная переменная

struct Country
{
char name[100];
char capital[100];
int population;
double area;
};

void DisplayCountries(Country *List); //описание функции

int main() {

Country* List;
List = new Country[n_Country];


for (int i = 0; i < n_Country; i++)
{
    cout << "Name = ";
    cin >> List[i].name;
    cout << "Capital " << endl;
    cin >> List[i].capital;
    cout << "Population " << endl;
    cin >> List[i].population;
    cout << "Area " << endl;
    cin >> List[i].area;
  }
    DisplayCountries(List);
}

void DisplayCountries(Country *List) //определение функции
{
cout << "--------- Result ---------------";
for (int i = 0; i < n_Country; i++)
{
    cout << List[i].name << ", " << List[i].capital << ", " << List[i].population << ", " << List[i].area << endl;
}
}
```

Размер в Вашем случае в функцию передавать не надо, тк у Вас размер - глобальная переменная. +Вам в комментарии уже показали, что функцию вывода надо сперва описать (тк она находится после функции main, из которой Вы её вызываете, она должна быть описана (или определена) до функции main, но после структуры, тк она выводит элементы типа этой структуры). Но вообще - это не лучший код, он компилируется - да, но вместо глобальной переменной лучше делать так, как Вам предложили в комментарии

Comment: А если наоборот написать функции перед main, они не будут получать заполненый массив?
Можете подсказать как правильно делать? Допустим я хочу ещё написать несколько функция для сортировки. Правильней их сначало объявить, а после main написать?

Comment: Вы можете определить её до функции main, при вызове функции вывода Вы же передаёте этот массив (а точнее указатель на первый элемент массива) в качестве аргумента

Comment: https://ravesli.com/urok-19-predvaritelnoe-obyavlenie-i-prototip-funktsii/ - здесь можете прочесть про описание (объявление) функции

Comment: О, это то что нужно, спасибо.